# Database Design - sales from multiple sources

Tags: sql, database

We currently have a SQL database with a table that holds online sales for our company, which sells products using other websites (say, Amazon).  The table schema has been set up to hold specific sale data/attributes provided by the website our items are currently sold on (say, Site A).

We are expanding sales to other websites that provide different attributes than Site A uses when an item is sold (e.g. Site A might provide a unique sales id number, and site B might not provide a unique sales id number, but also provide some other info that Site A doesn't provide that we still need to capture).

The question is do I add a separate table for sales on each 'site' that we sell on, as the schema will be different, or try to combine all sales into one table, no matter the platform, leaving some columns null if it doesn't pertain to the particular platform? Or maybe a hybrid approach, separating only the attributes that aren't common among the two sites into separate tables, while a "master" sales table holds attributes that are shared (sale_price, sale_date, etc)?

There are also other tables in play that hold internal information (product Ids, costs, etc), that are linked to the sales table via a unique identifier.  Whichever route I choose, I'd need come up with a unique identifier I could use across all tables (auto incremented sale_id, e.g.), and store that in a table for reference/joins.

Any suggestions are welcomed!

Comment: Do you have an inventory, what type of transactions you will be storing?

Comment: No, we use another system to track inventory.  This system just stores individual sales of products.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A sale is a sale >> same data belongs to the same table. I would definitely not recommend splitting your sales to several tables as this creates lots of difficulty for all that might follow: sales statistics and so on. Try to keep all sales in one table.

If it's a very small project, it might be the best shot to integrate the different fields into one table. Otherwise you might try to create profiles for every sale platform: In this case, use an Entity-Attribute-Value model.

Comment: Yes, I can imagine the effort in reporting with multiple sales tables.  This should affect a dozen or less fields that vary between the sites, so probably not worth going the EAV route. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Do not add a table for each site.  It sounds like you have a many to many relationship between sites and attributes, so set up your database that way.  Also, for any unique identifier you need, create it yourself.